# Is Geth's Clique PoA Consensus Algorithm production ready?

Tags: go-ethereum, clique, poa

Is it recommended to use geth's Clique PoA in a production setup or is it for test-net only? Does someone know of productive deployments of Clique PoA?

Comment: It does work. Rinkeby is running since last year without issues. But it is a testnet with low traffic it is not heavily tested like mainnet.

Answer (score 0):

Kaleido is running Clique PoA in a production setup for their customers.